# Error when starting oc4j

Tags: java, oc4j

I have an error when starting the oc4j. The path does not seem to be correctly specified for the jdk.[image]

The following shows the different folders; jdk, oc4j and jre[image]

My classpath is:

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: What have _you_ tried so far? What is your classpath setting?

Comment: Please add your PATH... Do you have your JAVA_HOME defined? could you add it here too?

Comment: System Variables: C:\%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Java\jdk1.5.0_22\bin

Comment: same for user variables